# Strengthen RGB colors using c#

Tags: c#, bitmap, rgb

I need to strengthen the RGB channel/colors with an number that the user can choose.
I've got the following code  , but i'm not sure that it's correct.
Can somebody tell me what i can change or can do better.

```
int value = int.Parse(textBoxConstante.Text);

for (int y = 0; y < myPic.Height; y++)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < myPic.Width; x++)
    {
        Color c = myPic.GetPixel(x, y);
        myPic.SetPixel(x, y, Color.FromArgb(c.R * value /10, c.G * value/10, c.B * value/10));
    }
}
```

Comment: Raise contrast?! What do you want to do in simple English?

Comment: What was the result when you ran this code?

Comment: @Jonas Moens - It compiles and runs fine, whats the problem?

Comment: We can't make it better unless we know what it's meant to do. As it stands, it's the best example of changing an image's colours pixel-wise by a tenth of a given multiplier that I've **EVER** seen!

Comment: @Oded , de RGB colors should be multiplied with the value a user choose.. in my code that value is 'int value'

Comment: @RitchMelton the problem is that i'm not sure that this is the right way to multiply the RGB values with an other value

Comment: @Jonas - Generally speaking, I don't think that there is a right way to multiply RGB. HSV/HSB sure, but RGB...not so much. What are you trying to accomplish.

Comment: @RitchMelton just trying to accomplish that an user can give a value , and with that value the RGB values of the picture should be multiplied, i also want that you can select an strengthen factor or weakening factor...

Comment: @Jonas Moens - That's where I'm confused, strength or weaken what aspect of the image? What does multiplying each of RGB channels do?

Comment: @RitchMelton the three color channels (RGB) of each pixel should be multiplied by a chosen constant , and the program provides a slider were  the user can set the amplification / attenuation factor between 0 and 5

Comment: @Jonas Moens - Ok, I'm still not getting it. Sorry. Contrast? Brightness? Saturation?

Comment: @Jonas Moens - Ahah! White balancing is slightly different linear operation that what your code is doing, but I think that's too OT at this point.

Comment: @RitchMelton can you give an code example of white balancing ?

Comment: @Jonas Moens - Not at the moment. The general idea (in RGB space) is to pick a color in the image and call it white, and then scale the color channels appropriately. There's good info on wikipedia for this.

Answer (score 1):

I've not run your code, but I suspect you're having problems with c# lack of implicit double casting... Try rewriting it this way:

```
.FromArgb((int)(c.R * ((double)value /10)), [the rest wrapped the same way]
```

Comment: I prefer the 'd' suffix on the 10 ((int)(c.R * (value / 10d)).